# Code for detecting Diabetic Retinopathy. When displaying the images using cv2, getting an error [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is the code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJPRD.png)

I am getting the following errors

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ff6N.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOiTX.png)

I am expecting to get all the images of the retinal scans in a tabular form

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] then click [edit] and correct your question.